# Erro ao gerar arquivo com PLSQL no oracle!

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

**Código**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CRIARARQUIVOTXT AS
  Arquivo_saida  UTL_File.File_Type;
  Dir_Arq   VARCHAR2(60);

Cursor cur_arq is 
  Select f.NOME from tfuncionario f;

BEGIN

-- Diretorio do Arquivo
Dir_Arq := 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\testes';

-- Abrindo o arquivo para a gravação
Arquivo_saida  := UTL_File.Fopen(Dir_Arq, 'teste.txt','w' );

-- Abrindo o cursor para realizar o loop das linhas que irão no arquivo
for Reg_Linha in cur_arq loop
  UTL_File.Put_Line(Arquivo_Saida, Reg_Linha.linha);
end loop;

-- Fechando o arquivo
UTL_File.Fclose(Arquivo_Saida);
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Arquivo gerado com sucesso.');

Exception
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Operação inválida no arquivo.');

UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
  WHEN UTL_FILE.WRITE_ERROR THEN
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Erro de gravação no arquivo.');

UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Diretório inválido.');

UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);
  WHEN Others THEN
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Problemas na gravação do arquivo.');

UTL_File.Fclose(arquivo_saida);


END CRIARARQUIVOTXT;
```

**Mensagem de erro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Select f.NOME Linha from tfuncionario f;    o erro é que "linha" deveria estar no cursor.

Comment: De que forma corrijo isso ?

Comment: corrigido: Cursor cur_arq is 
  Select f.NOME linha from tfuncionario f ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o problema foi linha codigo:

```
Cursor cur_arq is 
   Select f.NOME linha from tfuncionario f
```